# Can the moment estimator be not sufficient?

Tags: statistics, order-statistics, parameter-estimation

As the title, can the moment estimator sometimes be NOT sufficient? Consider the following example where Y ~ Uniform(1-b, 5+b):

From method of moment estimator: 
E[Y] = 1/2((1-b) + (5+b)) = 3 => Not useful
E[Y^2] = 1/12 (5+b - 1+b)^2 + 3^2= 1/12(2b+b)^2 + 9

Therefore, we set the second moment estimator m'2 to equal E[Y^2] and solve for b:

b = 1/2(sqrt(12(m'2 - 9)) - 4)

However, when we determine the sufficient stats by factoring, we will obtain that the first order Y(1) and last order Y(n) are minimally sufficient, meaning that m'2 is not sufficient. This seems weird to me because I though Moment estimators should always be sufficient. Is this true? Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: What would you think in the case that the moments don't exist.  For instance, the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Higher_moments) has no second (or subsequent) moment.

Comment: No, there is no guarantee moment estimators, when they exist, must be sufficient or function of sufficient complete.  For example, if $\theta=(\mu,\sigma^2)$ are the parameters of a distribution $P_\theta$, where $\mu=\mathbb{E}X$ and $\sigma^2=\operatorname{Var}X$ for $X\sim P_\theta$, then the moment estimator is $\hat\theta=(\bar{X},\frac{n-1}{n}S^2)$, which is not sufficient for e.g., the [logistic distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution).

Comment: This is an unusual parameterization of a uniform distribution. It seems obvious that $E(Y) = 3.$ so the mean of a sample is not going to give information about the only parameter $b.$

Comment: However, it is clear that the range (hence the variance) of the distribution increases with increasing $b,$ so the variance of a sample will be useful in estimating $b.$ Whether a function of the sample variance is the **best** estimator is up for discussion. I would guess that the difference between the maximum and minimum observations in the sample might be more useful. // There are important general principles, but when it comes to estimation, you have to treat each distribution according to its individual characteristics.